# NSNotification being fired off more then one time?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsnotificationcenter, observers

I am creating a sample player for a test project. I created a NSNotification to call a function to play the next audio track inside an array. The issue is the notification calls this function about 8 times in a row? I have no idea why this is occurring. Here is my code and thanks for the help!

```
let player = AVPlayer()

var urlPlayerItems = [String]()

var currentTrack: Int = 0



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Checks to see if player reached end
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.autoplayNextTrack(notification:)),
                                                    name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                    object: player.currentItem)

}

    func playTrack() {

        if urlPlayerItems.count > 0 {
            let newMovieURL = URL(string: urlPlayerItems[currentTrack])!
            asset = AVURLAsset(url: newMovieURL, options: nil)

            player.play()
        }
    }



    func autoplayNextTrack(notefication: NSNotification) {
        if (currentTrack + 1) >= urlPlayerItems.count {
            currentTrack = 0
        } else {
            currentTrack += 1
        }
        playTrack()
    }
```

Comment: try moving addObserver to viewDidLoad or remove it in viewWillDisappear

Comment: I tried this and still doesn't work. It's still getting called multiple times though when I remove the code from autoplayNextTrack and just put a print statement is calls it once?

Comment: Also when I comment playTrack() clan in autoplayNextTrack it doesn't call it more then once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the fact that an observer shouldn't be set multiple times, i think that you should reset the player to zero right before calling the play function again

```
func autoplayNextTrack(notefication: NSNotification) {
    player.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    if (currentTrack + 1) >= urlPlayerItems.count {
        currentTrack = 0
    } else {
        currentTrack += 1
    }

    playTrack()
}
```

Comment: A full sample of code with the suggestions would be great... I tried just about everything including what you just mentioned and couldn't figure it out . Thanks

Comment: I added the line to seek to 0 and it works now. I don't understand why adding that makes all the difference? Can you please explain since I was completely skipping to a new video all together. Why do I need to seek to 0?

Comment: Also it looks weird because you actually see the video seek to 0 after it ends

Comment: It is indeed not intuitif, i think apple developers are the one to give an explanation to this behaviour, it's like the asset reading index is stuck at the end of the asset, so when you call play again, the player sees it self at the end of the reading, so the notification is called again (hence the multiple times the notification was firing)... and you have to explicitly once you reached the end to reposition the reading index at Zero second if that makes any sense :)

Comment: Yeah this is very unintuitive. Is there anyway else to go about this?

Comment: That s all i found working for me, but that s not to say there is no other way. if this answer helped to get it working, accept it as the correct answer for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your observers in viewDidAppear method, you need to make sure you only add them **ONCE**. the viewDidAppear methods will get called multiple times.

Easy way is just to make a BOOL and flag it when you have added/removed it .

EDIT:
Also, I don't see any method where you remove the observer anywhere in your code, make sure you remove it too when you want to stop observing.

Example:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

or in your viewWillDissapear method.

Comment: I tried this and still doesn't work. It's still getting called multiple times though when I remove the code from autoplayNextTrack and just put a print statement is calls it once?

Comment: Sounds like your track can't be played to me.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I am not sure how you are running your entire code setup and how you are calling your playeritems. "if urlPlayerItems.count > 0 {" etc. Maybe store a reference to your AVPlayerItem as property, and add the notification to the actual playerItem instead of adding the notification to the player.currentItem helps you solve your issue . When you swap playerItems you need to make sure you remove the existing notificationobservers from the CURRENT playeritem before adding notifications to a new playerItem

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am really new to this so any examples of what you mean would be great!

Comment: @user7097242 The easiest way for you is to check out the Apple Sample codes, they are very good to look through and learn from. They show you exactly what you need. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html , please mark as answered if this solves your questions. :) you can download it here for Swift: https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOSUsingAVFoundationtoPlayMedia/Swift/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS

Comment: That is the sample code I am using currently but building on top of =] If I send this to you could you take a look at it?

Comment: @user7097242 I am not a Swift developer :( however, from your above code, you should basically just 1: removeObserver 2: replace AVPlayer playerItem, 3:  before you play the next item, add a new observer